# How to put an application in stop stage without destroing on back button?

Tags: java, android

I am developing server client application so my client android connected to server that is run in pc.

if i am in any other activity rather than main activity than I pressed back button than i go to previous one but when I pressed back button  when I was in home screen of my application than application destroy and go to home screen of mobile

so after that i hold on home button of mobile and again start my application although i am connected to pc than also i have to again give IP address and port number

so i have to solve it by using putting my application in stop stage when i pressed back button and again if  i select through hold on home button than back to main screen of my application without enter again IP and port

```
public void onBackPressed() {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);

    startActivity(new intent(mainactivity.this , home.class);

    return;
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please try rephrasing it.

Comment: What you mentioned is the default behaviour of android. Its the way it works. When you press back button current activity is popped from back stack ,destroyed and previous activity in the stack takes focus.

Comment: @Raghunandan is it really destroyed? Take a look at the lifecycle http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle - it's only destroyed iff the OS wants to destroy it, hence it needs its memory or something else.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong to put network client related code inside `Activity`. You ought to be using `Service` for that and bind or send commands to it from Activities.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you on the right way, doing some stuff on implementing onBeackPressed() method, but home button should be untouched.

However when you start your app t=you can use predefined settings for development.
For example: if DEVELOPMENT = true, use some stub IP.